# Wrapper package created by OracleApplicationsAdapter in BPEL SOA 11g shows as invalid

Tags: bpel, oracleapplications, oracle-soa

I am using OracleApplicationsAdapter to call a package. The procedure in this package returns record type. During configuration a wrapper package and procedure is created. But it is invalid if i check in database and all calls fails with error code

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at line 1 Check to ensure that the XML containing parameter data matches the parameter definitions in the XSD.

If i use DBAdapter for same procedure then it works fine. what could be the issue with OracleApplicationsAdapter ?